# How to get associated resources sorted in a specific way in a Ruby on Rails API

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-4

I have to model classes: TBMs and Locations
TBMs is the parent table and locations is the child table.
I have a fully developed RoR app for which I want to developed an API.
I started to develop an API/V1 controller for TBMs.

```
class Api::V1::TbmsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_tbm, only: [:show, :update]

  def index
    tbms = Tbm.order(:id)
    render json: tbms
  end 

  private
    def set_tbm
      @tbm = Tbm.find(params[:id])
    end

    def tbm_params
      params.require(:tbm).permit(:tbm_name, :chainage_direction).delete_if{ |k,v| v.nil? }
    end
end
```

I would like the index method when retrieves the two TBMs to include also the locations for each of them from child table Locations and sorted by daily date descending (locations to be enumerated starting with the most recent date).
The TBMs are already sorted ascending by their IDs (as shown in the returned JSON).

Here is the structure of my tables:

```
tbms
                                         Table "public.tbms"
       Column       |            Type             |                     Modifiers                     
--------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------
 id                 | integer                     | not null default nextval('tbms_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at         | timestamp without time zone | 
 updated_at         | timestamp without time zone | 
 tbm_name           | character varying(255)      | 
 chainage_direction | character varying(255)      | 
Indexes:
    "tbms_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_tbms_on_tbm_name" UNIQUE, btree (tbm_name)

locations
                                     Table "public.locations"
   Column   |            Type             |                       Modifiers                        
------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('locations_id_seq'::regclass)
 tbm_id     | integer                     | 
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | 
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone | 
 daily_date | date                        | not null
 station    | numeric(10,3)               | not null
 tbm_status | character varying(255)      | not null
 latitude   | numeric(12,8)               | 
 longitude  | numeric(12,8)               | 
Indexes:
    "locations_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_locations_on_tbm_id_and_daily_date" UNIQUE, btree (tbm_id, daily_date)
    "index_locations_on_tbm_id" btree (tbm_id)
    "index_locations_on_tbm_id_and_station" btree (tbm_id, station)
```

The curl command is:

```
curl -i -X GET \
   -H "Authorization:Token token=\"mytoken\", email=\"myemail@gmail.com\"" \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tbms/'
```

And the JSON returned is:

```
{
"tbms":[
{
"id": 1,
"tbm_name": "Denis",
"chainage_direction": "Ascending",
"created_at": "2014-11-13T19:00:00-05:00",
"updated_at": "2015-11-16T17:36:10-05:00"
},
{
"id": 2,
"tbm_name": "Lea",
"chainage_direction": "Ascending",
"created_at": "2014-11-13T19:00:00-05:00",
"updated_at": "2015-11-04T15:27:54-05:00"
}
]
}
```

I am testing my API with Chrome extension DHC by Restlet.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I would like the index method when retrieves the two TBMs to include also the locations for each of them from child table Locations and sorted by daily date descending (locations to be enumerated starting with the most recent date).

Comment: To make it simple, here is my question rephrased: I want to retrieve to two TBMs from the parent table sorted ascending by their IDs and in the same JSON response I want to have for each of them the daily locations retrieved from the child table (Locations) sorted by daily date descending, i.e. starting with the today's date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution relies on the locations controller and nested routes:

```
  #api
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users,     only: [:index, :create, :show, :update, :destroy]
      resources :sessions,  only: [:create]
      resources :tbms,      only: [:index, :edit, :update, :show] do
        resources :locations, only: [:index, :show]
      end
      resources :locations, only: [:index, :create, :show, :update, :destroy]
    end
  end
```

And changing the locations controller to accept parameters for the index method:

```
class Api::V1::LocationsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_location, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:tbm_id]
      locations = Location.where("tbm_id = '#{params[:tbm_id]}'").order("daily_date DESC")
    else
      locations = Location.order("daily_date DESC, tbm_id")
    end
    #locations = apply_filters(locations, params)
    render json: locations
  end

  def show
    render json: @location
  end

  def update
    if @location.update(location_params)
      render json: @location, status: 200, location: api_v1_location_path(@location.id)
    else
      return api_error(status: 422, errors: @location.errors)
    end
  end

  def create
    location = Location.new(location_params)
    if location.save!
      render json: location, status: 201, location: api_v1_location_path(location.id)
    else
      return api_error(status: 422, errors: location.errors)
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if @location.destroy
        head status: 204
    else
      return api_error(status: 422, errors: @location.errors)
    end
  end

  private
    def set_location
      @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    end

    def location_params
      params.require(:location).permit(:tbm_id, :daily_date, :station, :tbm_status, :latitude, :longitude).delete_if{ |k,v| v.nil? }
    end
end
```

And generating this kind of HTTP request:

```
curl -i -X GET \
   -H "Authorization:Token token=\"mytoken\", email=\"myemail@gmail.com\"" \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tbms/1/locations/'
```

Problem solved.